# Upload image and place cookie based on JSON variable in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, cookies

I'm trying to make a form work, with submitting from JavaScript and a variable from my JSON.
The general idea is to upload the file to a folder, and define the path in a cookie. I'm working in PHP. Somehow I just can't make the if statement return TRUE.

My code looks like this:
From functions.php

```
function SaveSelfieCam () {
 $currentQuiz = GetCurrentQuiz();
 if (!empty($_FILES[$currentQuiz->id])) {
 $myFile = $_FILES[$currentQuiz->id];

 if ($myFile["error"] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    echo "<p>Der skete en fejl.</p>";
    exit;
}

$name = preg_replace("/[^A-Z0-9._-]/i", "_", $myFile["name"]);

$i = 0;
$parts = pathinfo($name);
while (file_exists(QR_DIR . $name)) {
    $i++;
    $name = $parts["filename"] . "-" . $i . "." . $parts["extension"];
}

$success = 
move_uploaded_file($myFile["tmp_name"],QR_DIR . $name);
if (!$success) { 
    echo "<p>Det lykkedes ikke at gemme filen.</p>";
    exit;
}
if ($success) { 
echo "Alt er godt!";
setcookie($currentQuiz->id, QR_DIR . $name);
chmod(QR_DIR . $name, 0644);
}
}
}
```

HTML Form (from my index.php)

```
echo "<form id='form' action='' method='post'><input id='selfieCam' class='quizCam' type='file' capture='user' accept='image/*' name='" . $currentQuiz->id . "' onchange='submitSelfie()'><label for='selfieCam'>Til kameraet</label></form></div>";
SaveSelfieCam ();
```

JavaScript (submitting form):

```
function submitSelfie() {
     document.getElementById("form").submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add **enctype='multipart/form-data'** to your form as attribute-value like this

```
<form id='form' action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```